# sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities not returning results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, dmv

No doubt this is syntax or typo...but when I query sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities
for a parent table, I get zero results.  No error, just no results.

```
USE [source];
GO
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('[Test].[USERS]', 'OBJECT');
GO
```

When I view the dependencies from SSMS, I get

[image: SSMS dependencies]

I've never used this before, so maybe I am misunderstanding how this works or what it should be returning?  I tried against the SUBSCRIPTIONS table as well, same result...nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb630351.aspx):

> A table is tracked as a referencing entity only when it references a
>   Transact-SQL module, user-defined type, or XML schema collection in
>   the definition of a computed column, CHECK constraint, or DEFAULT
>   constraint.

Foreign key relationships would not show in this DMV.

Comment: Argh....missed that footnote!   Looked at it for too long and coulsn't see anything after a certain point.   Ultimate goal here is to query the parent child relationships in some inherited databases...but that's fodder for another question :)

Answer (score 3):

Referenced/referencing entity functions return instances where an object, column etc. is referenced directly (usually in other objects like stored procedures, but [Mark has the full list from the documentation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/136617/1186)).

These functions are not meant to analyze foreign key dependencies, which you can get from the foreign key catalog views. This simple query assumes all tables are in the `dbo` schema, but you would need to add joins to `sys.schemas` in order to flesh those out otherwise:

```
SELECT 'FK points from ', f.name, ' to ', t.name
  FROM sys.foreign_keys AS fk
  INNER JOIN sys.objects AS f 
    ON fk.parent_object_id = f.[object_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.objects AS t 
    ON fk.referenced_object_id = t.[object_id];
```

The query in your question will return results if you create an object that references the table, e.g.:

```
CREATE VIEW [Test].MyView_DeleteMe
AS
  SELECT * FROM [Test].Users;
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron...this gave me direction on what I was actually looking for.